# Return total of a GTM JavaScript variable (array) in another GTM JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

This is my very first question on this website, I am curious if someone could help me out. In Google Tag Manager I tried to set up a custom JavaScript variable with some jQuery that should return the total amount of all product prices within a specific array.

In the code below I return all product prices within an Enhanced Ecommerce dataLayer. In GTM, I have called this variable "{{product price}}".

```
function() {

var itemsInC = {{ecommerce.checkout.products}};

itemsincart = [];

for (var i = 0;i < itemsInC.length;i++) {

          priceincart.push(itemsInC[i].price);

    }

return priceincart;

}
```

The code above actually works and for example returns a value like: ['9.99', '21.95', '34.99'].

In the second piece of code I try to sum up the total of all returned values in the GTM variable "{{product price}}". However, the code below doesn't work properly. How could I return the total value of the script above in the script below?

This is what I created so far:

```
function() {

    var total = $("{{product price}}").each(function() {

                0 += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

    }

return total;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is normal to post an answer to my own question but I solved the issue above with the following code:

```
function() { var total = 0; for (var i = 0; i < {{product price}}.length; i++)
{ total += {{product price}}[i] << 0; } return total + ".00"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the exact code as you've got above, you've got a few syntax errors.

1. you don't need to wrap GTM variables in quotes
2. don't use parseInt because that just returns an integer. Use "Number" instead.
3. you left out a bracket

So you should probably use something like this:

```
function(){
   var total = 0;
   $({{product price}}).each(function(){
      total += Number(this);
   })
   return total;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nyuen, Thanks for your reply. I guess I was a little sloppy with my code. However, the code you set up didn't work either, the returned value stated NaN so something went wrong there. I fixed the issue in another way though, I used the following code: `function() {
 
var total = 0;
  
for (var i = 0; i < {{product price}}.length; i++) {

          total += {{product price}}[i] << 0;
  
    }

return total + ".00";

}
`